# Нужно изменить код на python. Чтоб отоброжался не отдельно в окне (GUi) а в терминале

Tags: python

Есть у меня код авторизации написанный на Python3. Но он при запуске отоброжается в отдельном окне, а нужно чтоб он отоброжался и запускался в терминале Ubuntu. Вроде задача лёгкая, но у меня чет не выходит. Надеюсь на Вашу помощь.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from tkinter import *
import os

def login_verify():
    username1 = username_verify.get()
    password1 = password_verify.get()
    list_of_dir = os.listdir()
    if username1 in list_of_dir:
        file = open (username1,"r")
        verify = file.read().splitlines()
        if password1 in verify:
            print ("Удачная авторизация")
        else:
            print ("Имя пользователя не найденно / неверный пароль")

    else :
        print ("Имя пользователя не найденно / неверный пароль")


def login():
    global screnn2
    global username_verify
    global password_verify
    username_verify = StringVar()
    password_verify = StringVar()

    screen2 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen2.geometry("500x300")
    screen2.title("login")
    Label(screen2,text="Please enter the information for login ",height= '2',width='30').pack()
    Label(screen2,text="",height= '2',width='30').pack()
    Label(screen2,text="логин : ",height= '2',width='30').pack()
    username_entry1 = Entry(screen2,textvariable = username_verify)
    username_entry1.pack()
    Label(screen2,text="",height= '2',width='30').pack()
    password_entry1 = Entry (screen2,textvariable = password_verify)
    password_entry1.pack()
    Label(screen2,text="",height= '2',width='30').pack()
    Button(screen2, text="Войти", height= "2",width="30", command = login_verify).pack()








def main_screen():
    global screen
    screen = Tk()
    screen.geometry("300x250")
    Label(text="Авторизация в AquaSpam").pack()
    Label(text="",height= '2',width='30')
    Button(text="Войти",height= '2',width='30',bg="blue",command = login).pack()
    Label(text="",height= '2',width='30').pack()
    screen.mainloop()




main_screen()


# screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Так а зачем вы используете tkinter?

Comment: Код писал не я, а знакомый. Связи с ним больше нет. Поэтому и не могу сделать отоброжение через терминал